# Why are the following congruent modulo 10?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Why does the following equivalence hold true? $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers. (This is part of a proof)

$ 123^m −33^n \equiv 3^m −3^n \pmod{10} \equiv 3^m(3^{n−m} −1) \pmod{10}
$

I understand that $ 3^m3^{n−m}=3^n $ and $-1(3^m)=-3^m$, but I don't understand why $3^m-3^n \equiv 3^n - 3^m\pmod {10}$.

Comment: The last statement doesn’t seem to be true..

Comment: Looks like a typo.  Easy to check particular cases.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$123\equiv 3 \mod 10\;\implies$$
$$123^m\equiv 3^m \mod 10$$

If $a\equiv b \mod c$

and $A\equiv B \mod c$

then
$a-A\equiv b-B \mod c$.

But the statement you did not understand is false with $(m=2;n=1)$.
$$3^2-3\equiv 6\mod 10$$
but
$$3-3^2=-6\equiv 4 \mod 10$$